# Wallpaper.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this plugin that allows youtube videos as a background: http://formstone.it/components/wallpaper

It looks really straight forward but it does not work. I do not receive any errors either. I recreated the demo on codepen here: http://codepen.io/bskousen/pen/MYyvEx

Is anyone familiar with this plugin and why its not working?

In my codepen I am linking to the jquery, the wallpaper js file, the wallpaper css file, and added this code:

```
$("#element").wallpaper({
source: {
    video: "//youtube.com/embed/xIuea-5m_yI"
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In the example that you linked, the #element div is zero size.

Add in the css:

```
#element {
  height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I needed to call it:

```
$(function(){
    $("#element").wallpaper({
        source: {
            video: "//youtube.com/embed/xIuea-5m_yI"
                }
          });
});
```

Comment: this is not really a function, its more the shorthand for "on document ready", means your code is executed when the document is loaded. Otherwise your function will obviously never be called.